# PDO with bound parameters sql query If statement in update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to create a 'trigger' not in the sql sense but I want to update the date_added field when the status field is set to 100

```
$sql='UPDATE table
SET status=:status,
    date_added=[PSEUDO CODE :status=100 ? now() : null;]
WHERE id=:id';

    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sign_id', $sign_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
```

1. Would it be better to attempt this in the sql query(*unsure how to
   perform this*) or on the php page (*think I could stumble through
   that one*) prior to issuing the query?
2. Are there any performance gains one way or the other?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `date_added = if(status=100, now(), null)`

Comment: @MarcB Wouldn't that be `:status=100` or would both work?

Comment: Why would you want it? what is the logic behind?

Comment: probably should be `:status` so you're getting the value you're updating with. `status` would be the current value in the field, which'd be the OLD value you're about to replace with the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date_added = :date

$date = $status == 100 ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s') : null;
$stmt->bindParam(":date", $date);
```

You can do this comparison in MySQL as well using `IF`.  I don't think that one is particularly faster than the other, but it makes more sense to me to use PHP for the comparison.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, you can't bind an SQL expression like `NOW()` with a query parameter. You *could* calculate the current date in PHP, and bind the resulting date value, assuming it's in the MySQL-friendly YYYY-MM-DD format. But then you also can't bind `null` without specifying `PDO::PARAM_NULL`.

Comment: Oh, yes have overseen this.. You need to prepare a proper data in PHP.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for pointing that out; I forgot that `NOW()` was not actually a string.  Using `date` should be fine.

Comment: After all I would say if you are comparing with `now()` using the mysql function will being better - no extra param has to be populated. If you compare with a certain date your solution is better, as you safely pass it using a prepared stmt

Comment: This might work, but be careful that the time emitted by `NOW()` and your application are roughly the same. In some cases you may have time-zone differences or without [ntpd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) then time skew.

Comment: this way did not work what i ended up doing was declaring the variable prior to binding it using ($date_removed = $status == 111 ?  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"):  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'; ) whic i see from the comments after i figured it out thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$sql='UPDATE table
SET status=:status,
    date_added=IF(:status=100, NOW(), NULL)
WHERE id=:id';
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
$stmt->execute();
```

But using the same parameter name twice in one statement only works if you configure PDO to use emulated prepare. If you use native prepare, then you should make distinct parameter names even for the same value:

```
$sql='UPDATE table
SET status=:status,
    date_added=IF(:status_again=100, NOW(), NULL)
WHERE id=:id';
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
$stmt->bindParam(':status_again', $status);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or else it'd be simpler to use positional parameters. You can also skip the bindParam() if you just pass an array of values to execute(). There's an example of the latter two changes together:

```
$sql='UPDATE table
SET status=?,
    date_added=IF(?=100, NOW(), NULL)
WHERE id=?';
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$status, $status, $id]);
```